# Project Tango not firing pose data with pose status=invalid

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm using the Java sdk. I've set my TangoConfig to have autorecovery=false, so that I can prompt the user to reset motion tracking whenever she sees fit after receiving a Tango pose data with status=invalid. Currently, whenever I get my device to fail at continuing motion tracking, I see that it stops giving me new pose datas in the listener callback, but I never get an PoseData that is invalid to signify that tracking has ceased. This all used to work for me, but recent versions of the SDK have failed to provide this callback as necessary. Anyone else experiencing something similar? Any ideas at what to look for to understand if something may be incorrect here?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using the Unity integration.

I also tried `getPoseAtTime()` with time values of 0 or Time.realTimeSinceStartup. But I never get a pose with with an invalid status.

I know of another developer who also has this bug, and says it was introduced about 3 months ago.

The [support page](https://developers.google.com/tango/support) says that Tango devs monitor this tag, so hopefully they'll read this and fix it!

The [UX Framework](https://developers.google.com/tango/ux/ux-framework) has an [exception](https://developers.google.com/tango/ux/ux-framework-exceptions#common_errorsexceptions) for loss of motion tracking. So that may be a work around in the meantime.

Comment: Exactly! It used to work perfectly and about 3 months ago it just stopped. Thought an update might fix it, but hasn't. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the exception. Will see if I can get a work around going for the meantime